# Flutter onTap method for Containers

Tags: user-interface, button, dart, flutter

Been developing a flutter app and dynamicly building some containers from some Firebase data. 
I wanted to know if there is a way to get a onTap method for containers (or any widget which is not a button ?

Here is a code sample :

```
  child: new Container(

    //INSERT ONTAP OR ONPRESSED METHOD HERE

    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
    child: new Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
          child: new GoogleUserCircleAvatar(snapshot.value['images'][0]),
        ),
        new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children : [
            new Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: new Text("${snapshot.value['name']}",
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
             ),
            new Text("${snapshot.value['description']}",
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
              ),
            ),
          ]
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You can wrap your `Container` in an [`InkWell`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell/InkWell.html) or [`GestureDetector`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html). The difference is that `InkWell` is a material widget that shows a visual indication that the touch was received, whereas `GestureDetector` is a more general-purpose widget that shows no visual indicator.

Comment: Another observation: InkWell spread out and cover all the container area to handle ontap event instead of GestureDector.

Answer (score 95):

You could wrap container inside an **Inkwell()** or in **GestureDetector()** as below

```
InkWell(                        
  child: Container(...),                        
  onTap: () {                          
  print("tapped on container");
  },                      
);
```

Using the **Gesture Detector**

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () { print("Container was tapped"); },
  child: Container(...),
)
```

The only difference between the two is InkWell provides a ripple effect when the pointer is in contact with the screen while this is no such visual feedback with GestureDetector.

Comment: thanks, I used GestureDetector but onTap not worked in free space only work when I click on child widget in the container but Inkwell was very good.

Comment: I had the same problem with GestureDetector. Surprisingly, by adding container's background color solved the problem.

Comment: for Reza and Donatas,maybe you need to set "behavior"  option of GestureDetector

Comment: If you use background color "Colors.transparent", then the GestureDetector will recognize taps (but the visual appearance is still the same).

Comment: As BuffK mentioned, setting `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque` fixes the empty-click issue. `HitTestBehavior.translucent` also fixes the issue and the difference is that the underlying widget will also receive event.

Answer (score 24):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

You can use both `GestureDetector` and `InkWell` but I'll suggest you to go for `InkWell` as it can show ripple effects which a `GestureDetector` can't.

**Differences between `GestureDetector` and `InkWell`:**

1. Both share many features in common like `onTap`, `onLongPress` etc. The main difference is that `GestureDetector` has more controls like dragging and so on. On the other hand, `InkWell` provides some nice ripple effects.
2. You can use either of them according to your needs. If you want ripple effect choose `InkWell`, and if you need more controls then go with `GestureDetector` or even combine both of them.

   ```dart
   Material(
     color: Colors.blue, // Background color
     child: InkWell(
       splashColor: Colors.grey, // Splash color
       onTap: () => print("Container pressed"), // Handle your onTap here.
       child: Container(height: 200, width: 200),
     ),
   )
   ```

Comment: I've been cracking my head trying to add the ripple effect to a Container with a InkWell. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 6):

Apart from what others have said in answers, if you use `Card` inside `InkWell`, then `InkWell` will hide away the ripply effect on Android—you can see it happening in the background but not on the card itself.

Solution to that is to create an `InkWell` inside the `Card`.

```
return Card(
  child: InkWell(
    child: Row(
      // Row content
    ),
    onTap: () => {
      print("Card tapped.");
    },
  ),
  elevation: 2,
);
```

This will help you gain the ripple effect and perform the tap captures on Android too.