# How do I make some text tappable (respond to taps) in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Assume I have some Flutter code like this:

```
  // ...
  body: new Center(
    child: new Text(
      'Hello, I am some text',
    ),
  ),
  // ...
```

How can I make the Text on the screen respond to a tap? (For example, simply printing to the log when I tap the text.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As seen on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317188/flutter-ontap-method-for-containers/44317228#44317228), you can use an InkWell or a gesture detector.

For example

```
InkWell(
    child: Text("Hello"),
    onTap: () {print("value of your text");},
)
```

Or

```
var textValue = "Flutter"
InkWell(
    child: Text(textValue),
    onTap: () {print(textValue);},
)
```

**EDIT** : As Collin Jackson suggested, you can also use a FlatButton

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {print("Hello world");},
  child: Text("Hello world"),
);
```

If you don't need or require material (FlatButton, InkWell, etc), you can use [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html):

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () { print("I was tapped!"); },
  child: Text("Hello world"),
)
```

Comment: is there a way to increase the tab area above and below the text by padding or anything similar?

Comment: FlatButton is deprecated so use TextButton

Answer (score 18):

you can use Rich text for tappable text:-

Divide the text in Text Span accordingly and use Tap Gesture in that text you want to make tappable.

```
  TapGestureRecognizer _termsConditionRecognizer;
  TapGestureRecognizer _privacyPolicyRecognizer;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _privacyPolicy.dispose();
    _termsCondition.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _termsConditionRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer()
      ..onTap = () {
        print("Terms and condition tapped");
      };
    _privacyPolicyRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer()
      ..onTap = () {
        print("Provacy Policy tapped");
      };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: 'By signing up you agree to the ',
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: 'Terms And Condition',
                recognizer: _termsConditionRecognizer,
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: ' and ',
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: 'Privacy Policy',
                recognizer: _privacyPolicyRecognizer,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please try to explain the answer rather than giving code snippet directly. It may help the community.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make the text appear in the form of a URL like so:

```
new FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {print("You've tapped me!")},
  child: Text(
    "Tap me!", 
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, decoration: TextDecoration.underline)),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

One more approach

Create the function that returns tapable widget:

```
Widget tapableText(String text, Function onTap) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: onTap,
    child: Text(text),
  );
}
```

Usage example:

```
...
child: tapableText('Hello', () { print('I have been tapped :)'); }),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these aproaches

1. TextButton and provide your text to it.
2. FlatButton and provide your text, to remove extra padding you can use
   materialTapTargetSize property of FlatButton and provide
   MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap but FlatButton is depreciated in newer version.
3. InkWell as discussed above.